# Integrating JSON feed with Backbone JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I'm currently working on a project where I type a keyword inside an input box and when I click send it hits a PHP server with a link like (localhost/json-status.php?query=**input text**) and it returns whatever is after "query=" in json format. Now I've accomplished this with jQuery and I'm trying to do this again in backbone js.

```
$("#updateStatus").click(function(){

   var query = $("#statusBar").val();

   var url = "json-status.php" + "?query=" + query;

   $.getJSON(url,function(json){
            $.each(json.posts,function(i,post){
         $("#content").append(
            '<div>'+
               '<p>'+post.status+'</p>'+
            '</div>'
         );
      });
   });
});
```

I've pretty much ported over what I did in jQuery over to backbone js and it's not working out as expected so far, please let me know if my approach is correct and how I can solve my problem.

backbone code:

```
(function ($) {
   Status = Backbone.Model.extend({
      status: null
   });

   StatusList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      initialize: function (models, options) {
         this.bind("add", options.view.addStatusList);
      }
   });

   AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: $("body"),
      initialize: function () {
         this.status = new StatusList( null, { view: this });
      },
      events: {
         "click #updateStatus":   "getStatus",
      },
      getStatus: function () {
         var url = "json-status.php" + "?query=" + $("#statusBar").val();
         var statusModel;

         $.getJSON(url,function(json){
            $.each(json.posts,function(i,post){
               statusModel = new Status({ status: post.status });
               this.status.add( statusModel );
            });
         });
      },
      addStatusList: function (model) {
         $("#status").prepend("<div>" + model.get('status') + "</div>");
      }
   });

   var appview = new AppView;
})(jQuery);
```

PHP server code which returns in json format (this works fine):

```
<?php
    $getQuery = $HTTP_GET_VARS["query"];

    $json='
    {"posts":[
        {
            "status": "' . $getQuery . '"
        }
    ]}
    ';
    echo $json;
?>
```

And if you wish to copy/paste what I have so far it's:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSON Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input value="What's on your mind?" id="statusBar" /><button id="updateStatus">Update Status</button>

    <div id="content">

    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#statusBar").click(function() {
            $(this).val("");
        });

        (function ($) {
            Status = Backbone.Model.extend({
                status: null
            });

            StatusList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                initialize: function (models, options) {
                    this.bind("add", options.view.addStatusList);
                }
            });

            AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: $("body"),
                initialize: function () {
                    this.status = new StatusList( null, { view: this });
                },
                events: {
                    "click #updateStatus":  "getStatus",
                },
                getStatus: function () {
                    var url = "json-status.php" + "?query=" + $("#statusBar").val();
                    var statusModel;

                    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
                        $.each(json.posts,function(i,post){
                            statusModel = new Status({ status: post.status });
                            this.status.add( statusModel );
                        });
                    });
                },
                addStatusList: function (model) {
                    $("#status").prepend("<div>" + model.get('status') + "</div>");
                }
            });

            var appview = new AppView;
        })(jQuery);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time.

---

Julien's code.

```
StatusList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Status,
    value: null,
    url: function(){ return "json-status.php?query=" + this.value;}
});

AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("body"),
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");// to solve the this issue
        this.status = new StatusList( null, { view: this });
        this.status.bind("refresh", this.render);
    },
    events: {
        "click #updateStatus" :"getStatus",
    },
    getStatus: function () {
        this.status.value =  $("#statusBar").val();
        this.status.fetch(this.status.value);
    },
    render: function () {
        var statusEl = $("#status");
        this.status.each( function(model) {
            statusEl.prepend("<div>" + model.get('status') + "</div>");
        });
    }
});

var appview = new AppView;
```

Full HTML (part 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>JSON Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input value="What's on your mind?" id="statusBar" />
        <button id="updateStatus">Update Status</button>

        <div id="status">

        </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#statusBar").click(function() {
                $(this).val("");
            });

            Status = Backbone.Model.extend();

            StatusList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: Status,
                value: null,
                url: function(){ return "json-status.php?query=" + this.value;}
            });

            AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: $("body"),
                initialize: function () {
                    _.bindAll(this, "render");// to solve the this issue
                    this.status = new StatusList( null, { view: this });
                    this.status.bind("refresh", this.render);
                },
                events: {
                    "click #updateStatus" :"getStatus",
                },
                getStatus: function () {
                    this.status.value =  $("#statusBar").val();
                    this.status.fetch(this.status.value);
                },
                render: function () {
                    var statusEl = $("#status");
                    this.status.each( function(model) {
                        statusEl.prepend("<div>" + model.get('status') + "</div>");
                    });
                }
            });

            var appview = new AppView;

        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And the PHP is still the same from the one originally documented.

Comment: Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: I believe the problem is here:
            `$.each(json.posts,function(i,post){
               statusModel = new Status({ status: post.status });
               this.status.add( statusModel );
            });`
It is able to load the number of posts just fine, but I'm not able to add it to the addStatusList. I believe it might be the "this" in this.status.add( statusModel) but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Well in your each this is not your view. It is the bound to the jquery. Outside your getJSON, do `var self = this` and then do `self.status.add(statusModel);`

Comment: Great! That fixed it. I also found that I had an error in my addStatusList function, it was applying the prepend to a nonexistent container. Thank you. I'll be posting the complete HTML in the answers for further reference. But one final question before I go, am I doing this correctly? As far as importing JSON into backbone.js goes. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for your general design, you should use a `Backbone.Model` and `Collection` to fetch your statuses:

```
Status = Backbone.Model.extend();

StatusList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Status,
  value: null
  url: function(){ return "json-status.php" + "?query=" + this.value;
});
```

Your view should be listening to the StatusList and not the StatusList creating a binding to the view:

```
AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $("body"),
  initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this, "render");// to solve the this issue
    this.status = new StatusList( null, { view: this });
    this.status.bind("refresh", this.render);
  },
  events: {
    "click #updateStatus":  "getStatus",
  },
  getStatus: function () {
    this.status.value =  $("#statusBar").val();
    this.status.fetch()
  },
  render: function () {
    var statusEl = $("#status")
    this.status.each( function(model){
      statusEl.prepend("<div>" + model.get('status') + "</div>");
    }
  }
});
```

There is a couple of things here:

- an attribute on the model is defined by set/get not by a js attributes like you did with status
- try to decouple stuff views know about models but models do not know about views

Comment: Ahh, this is what I was looking for. I had a feeling using $.getJSON wasn't the right way of importing JSON into backbone. This clears things up quite a bit, thank you. Now I tried implementing your code but I'm having a couple of issues, I've already went ahead and fixed what I think is all the syntax errors, but as of right now, whenever the updateStatus button is clicked, model.get('status') returns undefined. I've attached the syntax error free version of your code + my full code + the php that is being run in my initial question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. It turns out it was the PHP which was at fault.

Comment: Off topic... Julien, quick thank you for all your posts about Backbone on SO. Really helpful!

Comment: I am here to help. You can reach me on gtalk at julien.guimont@gmail.com for questions also.

Answer (score 1):

FYI 
(from the documentation)

We've taken the opportunity to clarify some naming with the 0.5.0 release. Controller is now Router, and **refresh is now reset**.

So if you are using the latest version dont forget to change *refresh* to *reset* in this line:

```
this.status.bind("refresh", this.render);
```