# My first backbone model / view. Am I on the right track?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The goal is to build a UI to select a make, size, and color for a T-shirt. Not all colors are available for every size, and not all sizes/colors are available for every make.

So the basic UI is three select elements for make, size, and color.

After reading a bunch of tutorials, I started out by creating models for Make, Size, and Color, and collections for Makes, Sizes, Colors, and views for each, and code to connect them.. and sort of lost my mind.

Second attempt is here, where I created a single "Confg" model, and a single "Config" view. The model as attributes for the current make, size, and color, and also attributes for the currently select-able makes, models, and colors.

Is this how you, you being a seasoned backbone.js expert, would have approached this?

Here's the model. Basically, I "manually" handle fetching correct sizes / colors in the setMake method, and correct colors in the setSize method, and then set the necessary changes on the model.

```
var design_id = 2; // set server-side

var ConfigModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function(){
      this.baseUrl = "/designs/" + design_id + "/configure/";
    },

    setMake: function(make_id){
      var me = this;
      var make = _.find(this.get("makes"), function(el){ 
                  return el.id == make_id });
      // aggregate changes to the model:         
      var changes = {
        "make": make
      };
      // get current make/size/color:
      var cur_make_id = make.id;
      var cur_size_id = this.get("size").id;
      var cur_color_id = this.get("color").id;

      // get sizes for the current make:
      $.getJSON(me.baseUrl + "makes/" + cur_make_id + "/sizes/",
           function(data){
            changes.sizes = data;
            if(!_.find(data, function(el){ 
                  return el.id == cur_size_id })){
            // the currently selected size is not available, 
            // so use the first size
            changes.size = data[0];
            cur_size_id = changes.size.id;
          }
        // and get the colors for the current make and size:
        $.getJSON(me.baseUrl + "makes/" + cur_make_id 
               + "/sizes/" + cur_size_id + "/colors/",
             function(data){
               changes.colors = data;
               if(!_.find(data, 
                      function(el){ 
                         return el.id == cur_color_id })){
                          // the currently selected color 
                          // is not available, 
                          //so use the first one in the list
                     changes.color = data[0];
                       }
                me.set(changes);
              });
         });
      },

    setSize: function(size_id){
      // retrieve colors for the new size
      var me = this;
      var size = _.find(this.get("sizes"), 
              function(el){ return el.id == size_id });
      var changes = {
        "size": size
      };

      var cur_make_id = this.get("make").id;
      var cur_size_id = size.id;
      var cur_color_id = this.get("color").id;

      $.getJSON(me.baseUrl + "makes/" + cur_make_id + 
                "/sizes/" + cur_size_id + "/colors/",
          function(data){
             changes.colors = data;
             if(!_.find(data, 
                function(el){ 
                  return el.id == cur_color_id })){
             changes.color = data[0];
          }
          me.set(changes);
      });
    },

    setColor: function(color_id){
      var color = _.find(this.get("colors"), 
             function(el){ 
                return el.id == color_id });
      this.set({"color": color});
    }
  });
```

Here's the model instance. The initial defaults are set server-side:

```
  var Config = new ConfigModel({
    design_id: 2,

    make: {"id": 1, "name": "Men's Organic Cotton Tee"},
    size: {"id": 4, "name": "L"},
    color: {"id": 2, "name": "Black"},

    makes: [{"id": 2, "name": "Women's Organic Cotton Tee"}, 
            {"id": 1, "name": "Men's Organic Cotton Tee"}],
    sizes: [{"id": 2, "name": "S"}, 
            {"id": 3, "name": "M"}, 
            {"id": 4, "name": "L"}],
    colors:  [{"id": 2, "name": "Black"},  
             {"id": 3, "name": "red"}]

  });
```

And here's the view. I think this is pretty straighforward.. bind to change events on the select elements and call setMake or setSize on the model, and then listen for change events from the model:

```
var ConfigView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#config"),

        optionsTemplate: _.template($("#options-template").html()),

        events:{
          "change #make select": "onChangeMake",
          "change #size select": "onChangeSize",
          "change #color select": "onChangeColor"
        },

        initialize: function(){
          Config.bind("change:makes", this.updateMakes, this);
          Config.bind("change:sizes", this.updateSizes, this);
          Config.bind("change:colors", this.updateColors, this);
        },

        render: function(){
        //console.log("ConfigureView.render");
        this.updateSelect("make");
        this.updateSelect("size");
        this.updateSelect("color");
        },

        updateMakes: function(){ 
          this.updateSelect("make");
        },

        updateSizes: function(){ 
          this.updateSelect("size"); 
        },

        updateColors: function(){ 
          this.updateSelect("color"); 
        },

        updateSelect: function(which){
          // updates the select specified by "which"
          this.$("#" + which + " select").html(this.optionsTemplate({
            chosen:Config.get(which),
            options:Config.get(which + "s")
          }));
        },

        onChangeMake: function(){
        Config.setMake(this.$("#make select").val());
        },

        onChangeSize: function(){
        Config.setSize(this.$("#size select").val());
        },

        onChangeColor: function(){
          Config.setColor(this.$("#color select").val());
        }
    });

    var app = new ConfigView();
    app.render();
```

Comment: Might I suggest some consistency with your variable names? In your `ConfigModel.setMake()` function you start using underscores but you're camelCasing everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Something tells me that your $.getJSON functions should instead be Backbone Collections.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection

Using collections instead of what you're doing will make your application easier to read and manage. Also using $.getJSON instead of backbone's collection kind of steers away from backbone's sole model.

Here is actually a question I posted not too long ago on StackOverflow which might relate to what I'm saying. Look at what Julien had to say.

[Integrating JSON feed with Backbone JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629972/integrating-json-feed-with-backbone-js)